# Having special characters in URLs in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, encoding, routes, special-characters

I want to have URLs like

> http://www.example.com/(*.)

but CodeIgniter does not allow me to do that. When I try to access some URLs I get 404 error (and the requested page exists).

I know I can set allowed characters in URL, but I thought about encoding it. However, if I do something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/<?php echo rawurlencode(string) ?>
```

or even:

```
http://www.example.com/<?php echo rawurlencode(rawurlencode(string)) ?>
```

I still got the 404. Why is that? '%'s are allowed characters, so why it won't work? And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can allow certain signs through **config/config.php** and the `permitted_uri_chars` key.

However, though I'm not fully certain, I do believe these are restricted by default to increase security. As relevant explanation suggests:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
```

For instance, what's so neat about the current settings is that you allow few enough uris to parse IDs without risking to have them compromised by `''`, `""` or similiar. Of course there's automatic and manual `$this->db->escape()`, but this just adds more failsafes.

Answer (score 0):

WHen trying to pass `urlencoded` strings to the `URI` it will generate an error if the encoded string has a `/`, codeigniter will try to parse this as a segment, thus rendering a `404`, what you need to use is query strings.

`$string = rawurlencode(string)`

`http://www.example.com/class/method/?string=$string`

then on your method

use `get`

```
function method()
{
   $this->input->get('string');

}
```

Comment: It ruins seo friendly urls and my whole conception of it's structure. In plain PHP I can achive what I want in 2-3 lines of code. How can I achive it in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have slashes `/` in the URL, use double raw encoding. For example:

```
$string = rawurlencode(rawurlencode('/sth/sth'));
```